# base url inside an iframe is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a web app hosted on `http://localhost:3000`
and on that web app, I have an iframe with `src="http://localhost:8000`

My problem is, relative paths inside that iframe is using `http://localhost:3000` instead of `http://localhost:8000` even if I have a base tag inside the iframe

main.html : `http://localhost:3000`

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8000"></iframe>
```

iframe.html : `http://localhost:8000`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="http://localhost:8000/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/index.css">
  <!-- this is using http://localhost:3000 instead of http://localhost:8000 -->
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Am I doing it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Nope, that won't be a problem. check in a separate tab, whether your localhost:8000 is working and reachable.

Comment: It works if I open it on a separate tab, but it's not working inside an iframe

Comment: Just curious...what happens if instead of `localhost` you use `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Else, try like this <iframe src="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.port=8080"></iframe>

Comment: @AndroidNoobie It's still not working, this time the iframe contents are using `http://127.0.0.1:3000` as base

Comment: @Aswin that would change the top level url and redirect me somewhere

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Here's what I did: (1) - Using [Fenix](https://github.com/coreybutler/fenix) I created 2 servers, one on Port 3000 and the other on 8000, (2) - Created `main.html` on server on Port 3000 using your HTML, (3) - Created `index.html` containing the iframe src on server on Port 8000 using your HTML, (4) - Start servers. The relative link in `index.html` is resolving to `localhost:8000` as expected due to the base URL being set. Also tested by adding a regular hyperlink and it worked too.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I updated my question, you can see on the attached image. When I hovered on the source attribute of a script tag, it shows that it's resolved to localhost:3000.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from your screenshot. Are those `script` tags in the document being served from the server on Port 3000? If so, then that makes sense. The `base` tag in the document being served from the server on Port 8000 only sets the base URL within that document. So the URLs in the document on the other server will still be on Port 8000.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie as you can see, the src attribute of the iframe is `http://localhost:8000` but the script tags inside was resolved to `http://localhost:3000`.  

-I attached the wrong screenshot, sorry.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to resolve this relative path issue within your iframe?  I am running into a similar issue and need to find a resolution.

Comment: 2 years since the last bump, looking for a solution for this! In my case, the "iframe" is the replit.com's Web View window that I have no control of